# "The model is probably unidentified" AMOS

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, amos

I am doing a CFA in AMOS and I keep getting the error message: "The model is probably unidentified. In order to achieve identifiability, it will probably be necessary to impose 1 additional constraint."

I have attached the model that I am trying to run. So I have 6 factors with 3 - 6 items in each factor. I have a sample of 350.

Is there anything wrong that I am doing with my analysis? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like you don't have one of the loadings from the first latent constrained to 1, but you do on the others. (It's very hard to say if all that you can paste is the amos path diagram though.)

Comment: You must give a weight of 1 to the first variable by pressing one of the arrows of the first variable and then typing 1..

Comment: @JeremyMiles A slightly more detailed version of this comment would make a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you don't have one of the loadings from the first latent constrained to 1, but you do on the others. Make sure each of the latent variable have at least a path to the observed variables fixed to 1. This is required for identifiability of the model.